# Using autoprefixer in grunt for the first time

Tags: gruntjs

I have the current version of npm installed and things seem to be OK:

The autoprefixer loads up just fine :

I created a file 'Grunfile.js'in the local project folder:

I am running this on windows 8.1

Where to from here? How do I tell grunt to check the file? How do I call the function from the command line ? Or do I call the function from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Within your directory you'll need to have 2 files, the package.json and the Gruntfile.js. To create a package.json file run the command `npm init`.

Next, you need to add the grunt-autoprefixer task to your package.json file which you can do by running `npm install grunt-autoprefixer --save-dev`.

Then, within the Gruntfile.js it should look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        // Task-specific options go here.
      },
      your_target: {
        // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
      },
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'autoprefixer'
  ]);

};
```

For more details on editing the settings on autoprefixer check out the documentation: https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer

To learn more about Grunt check out https://learngrunt.com

Comment: Thank you, I am caught on another project and need to get the auto-prefixing done by hand (no time to lose) I will try this solution on monday.